# .NET compatibility issues with Visual Studio 2013 Express solution

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a problem when referencing a DLL.

I do everything correctly:

**1.The DLL is built with no errors**

**2.I add it as a reference in my other solution**

However the system doesn't recognize it and I get the folowing error message:

**"Type or namespace could not be found.Are you missing an assembly reference?"**

I read on various forums and adjusted the .NET version of the DLL to match the .NET 4 on my project.I tried all versions 4/4-Client Profile/4.5 and none of them fixed the problem.The DLL,I checked with *.NET Reflector* and everything is there and working as it's supposed to.

Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Are there any warnings in the error list?

Comment: Start by closing your solution, removing bin and obj folders, re-opening and rebuilding your solution.

Comment: Yes,there was only one,refering to the .NET compatibility issue.It basically said my DLL is using 4.5 and my project is using 4-Client Profile.

Comment: I restarted and rebuilt everything at least 4 times.

Comment: Well, this is actually something you should take care of. Just change the .NET Framework of the DLL in its project settings to 4.0 instead of 4.5, then try what codemonkey said.

Comment: "I tried all versions 4/4-Client Profile/4.5 and none of them fixed the problem."

Comment: i had this problem once. try setting **both** your dll and the project that uses it to target .net Framework 4 Client Profile, and than **restart** vs. see if it works for you

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default framework for a class library to be 4 ,instead of 4.5 from the beginning?